# Как сделать SELECT из MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

есть таблица (**clients**), в которой хранятся строки вида

id|user|text

другая таблица (**users**), в которой хранятся пользователи, закрепленные за клиентами

id|fio

связь между таблицами: clients.user=users.id

когда делаю SELECT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    user,
    COUNT(clients.id) AS cnt
FROM
    clients
GROUP BY
    user
```

возвращается результат вида: `сотрудник|кол-во клиентов, закрепленных за ним`, но только для тех сотрудников, за кем закреплен хотя бы 1 клиент (т.е. если в clients есть строка, содержащая user, соответствующий id сотрудника)

насколько я понял, GROUP BY необходимо работать хотя бы с одной строкой, для получения результата. как быть, если нужен список с 0?

т.е. итоговый результат хочется видеть таким:

```
user|cnt
1   |1
2   |1
3   |5
4   |0
5   |0
6   |29
```

сейчас результат такой:

```
user|cnt
1   |1
2   |1
3   |5
6   |29
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добрый день. Попробуйте следующий запрос (насколько я понял, он решит Вашу задачу).

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    COUNT(clients.id)
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    clients
ON
    clients.user = users.id
GROUP BY
    users.id
```

То есть, Вам, судя по всему, необходимо использовать левое соединение при получении данных.
Опробовал данный запрос на MS SQL, всё работает так, как надо.

UPD:
Можете попробовать ещё вот так вот, может работать быстрее. У меня на тестовой базе дало корректные данные.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    users.id,
    COUNT(clients.id) AS cnt
FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN
    clients
    ON users.id = clients.user
GROUP BY
    users.id
```

И ещё вариант, с вложенным запросом. Думаю, он будет у Вас работать быстрее всего.

```
SELECT
    id,
    ISNULL(tbl.cnt, 0)
FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        user,
        COUNT(clients.id) AS cnt
    FROM
        clients
    GROUP BY
        user) AS tbl
    ON users.id = tbl.user
```

Ну и без вложенного запроса, через временную таблицу:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        user,
        COUNT(clients.id) AS cnt
INTO #tbl
    FROM
        clients
    GROUP BY
        user
;

SELECT
    id,
    ISNULL(#tbl.cnt, 0)
FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN
    #tbl
    ON users.id = #tbl.user
```

Comment: не подошло, т.к. выборка очень долгая (в таблице clients миллионы строк)

Comment: @ultrabatya А Ваш запрос по таблице `clients` отрабатывает быстро?

Comment: @ApInvent да, быстро

Comment: @ultrabatya Добавил в свой ответ ещё вариант, возможно, поможет :) P.S. Как вариант, можно попробовать выгрузить Ваш результат во временную таблицу, а потом просто сделать Left Join с таблицей users. Сейчас попробую накидать запрос.

Comment: Думается, что и этот вариант будет работать медленно. Обратите внимание, у топикстартера запрос обращался лишь к таблице clients, и работал быстро не смотря на большие объемы. Но по сути - это связи клиент-сотрудник и из нее не получить не существующие связи. Приходится связывать с сотрудниками и искать не существующие, что вы собственно и сделали. Только, вот, на базе, похоже, индексов нужных не хватает. explain бы.

Comment: @ultrabatya, я ещё дополнил свой ответ, посмотрите третий запрос в нём. Если и он не поможет - надо действительно, как писал Vitalts, смотреть внимательнее на структуру БД.

Comment: @Vitalts, накидал запрос с соединением со вложенным запросом. С моей точки зрения, это "костыли", но если у автора быстро работает его запрос, который я поместил во вложенный, то, думаю, третий запрос из моего ответа должен дать максимальную производительность. Не думаю, что из таблицы users выборка будет долгой.